# Algebra - can someone please break this down for me?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can someone please break down each step of this algebra for me? It's simple, but I just can't seem to follow it.

$\cfrac{1}{\left(1-\left(\cfrac{5}{6}\right)\right)^2}$

I know the answer is $\cfrac{1}{\frac{1}{36}} = 36$, but I just can't get there. A detailed break down of each step would be extremely helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We want to evaluate $$\frac{1}{(1-\frac{5}{6})^2}.$$

Let's work with the denominator first. We have $$1-\frac{5}{6} = \frac{6}{6}-\frac{5}{6} = \frac{6-5}{6} = \frac{1}{6}.$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Ah yeah, I got it. Thanks! Squaring 1/6th is 1/36 and 1/(1/36) is 36.

Answer (score 3):

$\cfrac{1}{\left(1-\cfrac{5}{6}\right)^2}=\cfrac{1}{\left(\cfrac{6}{6}-\cfrac{5}{6}\right)^2}=\cfrac{1}{\left(\cfrac{6-5}{6}\right)^2}=\cfrac{1}{\left(\cfrac{1}{6}\right)^2}=\cfrac{1}{\cfrac{1^2}{6^2}}=\cfrac{1}{\cfrac{1}{36}}=36$